# Dismiss View Controller from Modal

Tags: ios, swift, dismiss, navigationcontroller

I've a `MainTabBarController` with multiple controllers.
In my `FirstTabViewController` (embed in `UINavigationController`) I pushed to another View Controller, like: `navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)`.

In this controller, I've to show a modal view controller, like:

```
let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SomeViewController") as! SomeViewController

vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
vc.modalTransitionStyle = .coverVertical

let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
self.present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And in the `SomeViewController`, I've to dismiss this controller like: `self.dismiss(animated: true)` but it pop automatically to root view controller (`FirstTabViewController`).

My question, why ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Present `SomeViewController` on your current controller not on the `navigationController`.

**So Changed line:**

```
self.navigationController?.present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**To:**

```
self.present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: @Idnext When you present like this what happened when you dismiss the `SomeViewController` ?

Comment: The `FirstTabViewController` appear ... like a popToRoot effect

Comment: @Idnext Are you sure that from firstViewController to SecondController you are moving using pushViewController because it looks like you are presenting secondViewController too instead of push

Comment: @Idnext Try once commenting these two lines `vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
vc.modalTransitionStyle = .coverVertical` and check now it is dismissing properly ?

Answer (score 1):

_ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

```
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```